# Audit Log Module For Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, smarty-plugins

We are using smarty 3.x for one of our project. Now we need to log each and every action. Also we have to save the existing data and new data in log table in database. So Is there any module available in smarty for audit log ? If yes then can you please share the link ? 
If no then is there any way to handle this from central point ?

Comment: are you looking to log data in database using Smarty ? it's not possible , you can try it using PHP

Comment: Can you share some examples of what you want to log? Smarty is a templating system and should in no way be used for any actions that need to be logged - that's part of your application